# Flutter - how to update change in all ViewModels when a ViewModel has made a change in a Model's property

Tags: flutter, mvvm, stacked

I'm using stacked package (https://pub.dev/packages?q=stacked) as MVVM architecture in Flutter. I need to update a change in BaseModel when a ViewModel change a property in a service class. Here is the summary of my code.

```
class BaseModel extends ChangeNotifier {

  final AuthenticationService _authenticationService =
  locator<AuthenticationService>();

  AppUser get currentUser => _authenticationService.currentUser;

}

class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirestoreService _firestoreService = locator<FirestoreService>();

  AppUser _currentUser;
  AppUser get currentUser => _currentUser;

updateUser(AppUser user) {
    _currentUser = user;
  }

}

class UserProfileViewModel extends BaseModel {
final AuthenticationService _authenticationService = locator<AuthenticationService>();

Future updateUser() async{    
    AppUser user = AppUser(many properties);    
    await _authenticationService.updateUser(user);    
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

When I call UserProfileViewModel.updateUser(), the _currentUser in AuthenticationService change sucessfully, however the currentUser in BaseModel doesn't synchronize the update.

What I have tried:
I have tried observable_ish package, however, when I implement the ReactiveServiceMixin in my AuthenticationService and wrap the _currentUser in an RxValue, I can't set the initial value. Also, other functions in AuthenticationService which pass _currentUser as an argument, get error message too. Like this:
await _firestoreService.createUser(_currentUser);

Answer (score 1):

You have to update `currentUser` on `BaseModel`. I'm unsure for the reason to have `UserProfileViewModel` inherit `BaseModel`. Inheriting the class won't pass the values.

```dart
class BaseModel extends ChangeNotifier {

  final AuthenticationService _authenticationService = locator<AuthenticationService>();

  AppUser get currentUser => _authenticationService.currentUser;

  // Update user
  void update(AppUser user) {
    _authenticationService.updateUser(user);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```